# Mounting a WD Livebook share on raspberry Pi using fstab

Tags: mount, fstab, cifs

I have managed to successfully mount a WD Livebook share (called tv with Public access) using the following command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o credentials=/smb-credentials,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,rw,soft,sec=ntlm,vers=1.0 //192.168.0.18/tv /home/pi/livebook
```

However, I would like to do this automatically by amending /etc/fstab. But doing that just doesn't seem to work. Here is the line I added to the fstab file:

```
//192.168.0.18/tv /home/pi/livebook cifs credentials=/smb-credentials,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,rw,soft,sec=ntlm,vers=1.0 0 0
```

Help would be much appreciated. I'm new to this but have got shares on a WDMirror mounting automatically but not with the WDLiveBook? Seems very odd.

Cheers

Andre

Comment: What exactly does "doesn't seem to work" mean? What have you done after inserting that line into `/etc/fstab`, and what was the result? Was there an error message?

Comment: Hi .. when I run the command line version a folder with a mount icon appears on the desktop and the files from the share arer visible in it ..  when I reboot and the fstab runs I was expecting the same to happen but it isn't there. There is a /home/pi/livebook folder but nothing in it. Let me try again and make it clearer. I'm not sure where an error message will be. Also now I think about it I am wondering if the home folder is the right place for this?

Comment: Messages from the processing of `/etc/fstab` should be in `/var/log/syslog`. Also try the command `sudo mount -a` and see whether it produces any error message.

Comment: Hi .. thanks I'll take a look at both those options. I've changed the folder from /home/pi/livebook to /wdmirror to avoid using the home folder ..still works for the command line version as /wdmirror now shows the files and directories of the share ... but the fstab didn't mount the share. Running sudo mount -a gives me a mount error(22) invalid argument refer to mount.cifs(8) manual page ...I'm checking the log but it's quite long and I'm scrolling down to the end!

Comment: The log says CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -22

Comment: That means you have some syntax error in your `/etc/fstab` line. Doublecheck there are no strange characters, stray spaces or the like.

Comment: also try `mount -a -v` (verbose option) to make it give a bit more information.

Comment: Hi @Tilman .. thanks for your help I have now got it working. I'd obviously gone round in circles trying all sorts and had _vers=3_ rather than _vers=1.0_. I'm pretty sure that I had tried this before without success so I think that changing to _/wdmirror_ from _/home/pi/livebook_ also made a difference. I may try moving back to _/home/pi/livebook_ and see if it fails. Then I will post the answer below. Many many thanks for taking the time to help and get this working.

Comment: Yep .. I changed _/wdmirror_ to _/home/pi/livebook_ and that didn't work. I think the directory needs to be part of the root structure .. there may be something about the directory _home_ that it doesn't like!

Answer (score 1):

I now have this working.

There were two things which I changed:

1. A typo in the /etc/fstab file .. the line in the question above is correct. however ...
2. More importantly after some testing I created a new directory */wdmirror* changed its ownership to the user I log in with **pi**. Changed permissions to read and write as well. Using the */wdmirror* directory instead of */home/pi/livebook* worked fine. It may something about the home directory it doesn't like - I'm no expert so will need to read more about that.

The correct line in fstab is now:

```
//192.168.0.18/tv /wdmirror cifs credentials=/smb-credentials,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,rw,soft,sec=ntlm,vers=1.0 0 0
```